# Nested ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded

Tags: client-object-model

Has someone worked with nested ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded?
How/where should i notify the external one that the internal has finished (the internal ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded has a clientContext.executeQueryAsync)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done that a few times. Basically the contents of the external clause won't be executed until the notification so you have to ensure that the notification is outside of the external clause otherwise the whole code block inside of the external clause won't run.